# Way to detect that stack area is not overlapping RAM area during runtime

Tags: c, stack-overflow, microcontroller, ram, iar

Is there any way to check or prevent stack area from crossing the RAM data (.data or .bss) area in the limited memory (RAM/ROM) embedded systems comprising microcontrollers? There are tools to do that, but they come with very costly license fees like C-STAT and C-RUN in IAR.

Comment: The stack is allocated in RAM so I take it you refer to the `.data` and `.bss` segments?

Comment: yes that is correct !

Answer (score 3):

You need no external tools to view and re-map your memory layout. The compiler/linker you are using should provide means of doing so. How to do this is of course very system-specific.

What you do is to open up the system-specific linker file in which all memory segments have been pre-defined to a default for the given microcontroller. You should have the various RAM segments listed there, de facto standard names are: `.stack` `.data` `.bss` and `.heap`.

Each such segment will have an address range specified. Change the addresses and you will move the segments. However, these linker files usually have some obscure syntax that you need to study before you touch anything. If you are (un)lucky it uses GNU linker scripts, which is a well-documented, though rather complex standard.

There could also be some manufacturer-supplied start-up code that sets the stack pointer. You might have to modify that code manually, in addition to tweaking the linker file.

Regarding the stack: you need to check the CPU core manual and see if the stack pointer moves upwards or downwards on your given system. Most common is downwards, but the alternative exists. You should ensure that in the direction that the stack grows, there is no other read/write data segment which it can overwrite upon stack overflow. Ideally the stack should overflow into non-mapped memory where access would cause a CPU hardware interrupt/exception.

Here is an [article](http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/2014/02/are-we-shooting-ourselves-in-the-foot-with-stack-overflow/) describing how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In small micros that do not have the necessary hardware support for this, a very simple method is to have a periodic task (either under a multitasker or via a regular timed interrupt) check the 'threshold' RAM address which you must have initialized to some 'magic' pattern, like 0xAA55

Once the periodic task sees this memory address change contents, you have a problem!

Comment: this only checks for stack overflow.  it does not check for stack corruption

Comment: And the title says: "Way to detect that stack area is not overlapping RAM area during runtime"!

Answer (score 1):

In microcontrollers with limited resources, it is always a good idea to prevent stack overflow via simple memory usage optimizations:

- Reduce overall RAM usage by storing read-only variables in non-volatile (e.g. flash) memory. A good target for this are constant strings in your code, like the ones used on `printf()` format strings, for example. This can free a lot of memory for your stack to grow. Check you compiler documentation about how to allocate these variables in flash.
- Avoid recursive calls - they are not a good idea in resource-constrained or safety-critical systems, as you have little control over how the stack grows.
- Avoid passing large parameters by value in function calls - pass them as `const` references whenever possible (e.g. for structs or classes).
- Minimize unnecessary usage of local variables. Look particularly for the large ones, like local buffers for example. Often you can find ways to just remove them, or to use a shared resource instead without compromising your code.

Comment: can local be changed to global or static?Zero initialized will be good or uninitialized is better?But I am afraid they will be adding up to the RAM size.Isnt?

Comment: Changing to static isn't very helpful I think, because you would only save memory in reentrant functions, but you probably don't want to use static variables on them anyway. But it would be easier to predict memory usage if you are analyzing your code without using any fancy tools (e.g. just checking a .map file). You could use shared global variables, but it's not good coding practice and can compromise modularity, so I would only consider it where too much memory is being used. But it really depends a lot on the complexity of your program. If it's simple, using a few globals is usually OK.

Comment: It won't make any difference it the variables are initialized or uninitialized. In terms of using global variables (and I really mean buffers and large classes/records), you might be able to pass references around for them in elegant ways, without compromising the quality and modularity of the code.